# Error 1075: The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion

Tags: windows-8, streaming, windows-media-player

I'm unable to stream content to my TV anymore from Windows Media Player. It worked fine until about a month and a half ago. The only thing I can think that I did was I turned some Windows features off in the Control Panel.

In Windows Media Player, I go to the Stream drop down menu located at the top, click on Turn on media streaming..., takes me to the Network and Sharing Center located in the Control Panel, and then fails to turn media streaming on. Then when it fails, there's a link to Windows Services. I scroll down and find WMPNetworkSvc, try to turn it on, and then I receive the Error 1075.

I've tried turning off Media Player in Windows features, rebooting, then turning it back on. I've also tried turning off every Windows feature, and then turning all the ones I use, back on. I've troubleshooted on Google, but all of the fixes were for Windows Vista or earlier. There was another solution I found, but it required deleting a registry file and I don't want to mess with my registry unless I'm assured it works.

ASUSTek K53Z laptop, Windows 8 x64 Pro 9200, AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Pictures

[image]

[image]

Update: I'm running a sfc /scannow in cmd (administrator mode), and I'll see if this fixes the missing dependency or service.

Update: No, sfc /scannow didn't do anything.

Comment: click into the Dependency tab. Here you see a list of services. Make sure all of them are started correctly.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that.  I tried check marking the HTTP activation in .NET framework found in Windows features.  It didn't change anything.  Is there a way to reset all my Windows features to default?

Comment: HTTP is the HTTP.sys driver and not the .net HTTP thing. Is the Windows Search service running?

Answer (score 5):

Error 1075 may imply that one of the services it depends on doesn't exist.

You can see which services it depends on by running `sc qc ServiceName` from a Command Prompt (`sc.exe` if from PowerShell) - adjusting the service name if yours is something different - and checking the `DEPENDENCIES` section.

Note that Service Manager (services.msc) does not show dependency services if they do not exist, whereas the command above lists all dependencies.

The Event Logs may also tell you which service is failing, in Windows Logs -> System, under [Event ID 7003](http://kb.eventtracker.com/evtpass/evtpages/EventId_7003_ServiceControlManager_44393.asp).

https://serverfault.com/q/24821/236916 gives a couple of methods for changing dependencies for a service - you can do it with `sc` by running something like `sc config ServiceName depend=All/The/Existing/Dependencies/Except/The/One/You/Want/To/Remove` from an Elevated Command Prompt.

It's probably worth saying though, that this won't address the underlying question of *why* that service ceased to exist.